# Replace line in config file with batch afterward start exe

Tags: batch-file

With a batch file, I want to change a value in a configuration file:

```
"title.connectionString" : "ServerIP",
```

ServerIP is the variable to be changed. So the batch file has to give people who use it an option to choose from 4 prefixed IPs. After they selected one of the 4 the IP, the config file has to be saved with new value and the batch file should run an executable.

Has anyone got an idea how I can do this with a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, try this code:

```
@echo off
:start
Echo Select Ip:
Echo.
Echo     1. 10.0.0.0
Echo     2. 10.0.0.1
Echo     3. 10.0.0.2
Echo     4. 10.0.0.1
Echo.
Choice /c 1234 /m "Ip: " /n 
set choice=%errorlevel%
set ip=
if %choice%==1 set ip=10.0.0.0
if %choice%==2 set ip=10.0.0.1
if %choice%==3 set ip=10.0.0.2
if %choice%==4 set ip=10.0.0.3
if "%ip%"=="" (Echo Error, null variable & goto :start) 

ren config.txt config.tmp
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (config.tmp) do (
set line=%%a
Echo !line:ServerIP=%ip%! >> config.txt
)
del config.tmp
```

And that should do what you want.

Mona

Comment: also the exact string ServerIP is not in the config, it can be any other ip

Comment: it can be an IP or domain name with or without port, so the value is unknown

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    call :replaceKeyValue "file.config" "title.connectionString" "123456789"

    endlocal

exit /b

:replaceKeyValue file key value
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    ren "%~f1" "%~nx1.tmp" >nul && (
        (for /f tokens^=1^,*^ delims^=^:^ eol^= %%k in ('findstr /n "^" ^<"%~f1.tmp"') do (
            echo(%%l|findstr /c:"\"%~2\"" >nul && (
                for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%v in ("%%l") do echo(%%~v : "%~3",
            ) || (
                echo(%%l
            )
        )) > "%~f1" 
        del "%~f1.tmp" > nul
    )
    endlocal
```

This will handle the replacement of the value in the file. Monacraft answer shows a perfect way of selecting the required ip.

This will rename the file to file.tmp and for each line in the file (findstr /n is used to avoid lost of empty lines) it is tested agains the passed key. When required line is found, it is split using the colon (to keep the indentation) and value replaced with supplied value. All the non matching lines are echoed as is. All the output of the process is send to the original file and at end, the .tmp file is deleted.